# Create a smaller list from data in a larger list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need some help in creating a list using information that is contained in a larger list in Excel.  For instance, in cells A1:A15 I have a persons name.  In cells B1:B15 I have a drop down box indicating Pass/Fail.  I am only interested in the people who have failed, so is there a way to create a smaller list that will contain their name based on if they have the Fail designation in cells B1:15? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula, say in `E2`:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$15,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$15="Fail",ROW($B$1:$B$15)),ROW()-ROW($E$2)+1))
```

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it and drag it down.

[image]

Another way would be to filter column `B` for `Fail` values and copy only visible rows

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, worked like a charm!

Comment: I ran into a slight problem with the formula you gave me.  I neglected to mention that I have multiple columns with pass/fail for each name.  So I need a formula that will return the same list when a person has failed any of the tests that they have taken. So if Name1 has five tests and are pass,pass,pass,fail,fail I would like their name to show up on a list, and for anyone who has passed every test, they be excluded from the list.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: use something like this: `=INDEX($A$1:$A$15,SMALL(IF(($B$1:$B$15="Fail")+($C$1:$C$15="Fail")+($D$1:$D$15="Fail"),ROW($B$1:$B$15)),ROW()-ROW($E$2)+1))` with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: Total life saver, thank you again for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this small macro:

```
Sub SmallerList()
    K = 1
    For Each r In Range("B1:B15")
        If r.Value = "Fail" Then
            Range("C" & K).Value = r.Offset(0, -1).Value
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```