# Loop and Grab box to the right

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I'm currently working on a project that requires loops which I'm not to sure how to go about doing.. I have the information in blocks so for each client I have a bunch of information so for instance I will have A1 say Name:  and B1: say Bob,

Then A17 will be again Name: B17: George

This keeps going for approximately 1000 rows. I need to find a way to circulate through all of the material and grab all the names and place them in a column following each other. 
I guess I'm looking for a loop that finds name gives me the value to the right, and then it keeps doing that all the way down.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: build a model. an array model cause it's quite easy to transpose to a different view ( vertical/column view ). Build an array that will iterate horizontally and grab all the 16 cells then go on to its 2nd row.

Comment: Hey i'm not sure how to go about that, because I have the information in two different columns for each person.. so it would have C1 Saying date of Birth A2 Age B3 Sex etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple...........say your names are stored in column **B** in cells B1, B17, B33, B49, ...basically 16 rows apart...Then in cell C1 enter:

```
=INDIRECT("B" & 16*ROW()-15)
```

and copy down.  This is good for **evenly spaced records**

**EDIT#1**:

Since the records are not evenly spaced..........in **C2** enter the following array formula:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$1000,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$1000="Name",ROW($A$1:$A$1000)),ROW()-ROW($C$2)+1))
```

and copy down.

This is an **Array Formula** .  **Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Something like:

[image: pic]

Adopted from [simocos post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591967/create-a-smaller-list-from-data-in-a-larger-list/22592065#22592065)

Comment: The problem is that they are not evenly spaced, they intially come from word

Comment: well they contain a bunch of categories, A1 Name A2 birth etc

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot, is there anyway to through this into a macro which will do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

in C1 enter this formula : (with Ctrl+ shift + Enter)

```
= IFERROR( INDEX($B$1:$B$1000; AGGREGATE(15;6;(ROW($B$1:$B$1000)-ROW($B$1)+1)/($B$1:$B$1000<>"");ROWS(C$1:C1)));"")
```

then copy the cell down
(the formula is not from me. I use it in one of my workbooks, and adapted it)