# What does each line in the code for a small list mean and how do I change them to fit my needs?

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula

I want to have a continuously updating smaller list of items from a larger list in Excel. For instance, in cells A1:A15 I have a question #, cells B1:B15 are where I put in an answer, either a,b,c, or d. Cells C1:C15 are the correct answer, cells D1:D15 I have an IF/Then statement of IF(B1=C1,1,0) I am only interested in the questions that I have gotten wrong, so is there a way to create a smaller list that will contain just a list of incorrectly answered questions? Also Is it possible to have the Values from A1 though D15 be on one sheet and smaller list is populated in another sheet on the same workbook and to have the list not start at the top of the column but a couple cells down?

I found this code on this website [Create a smaller list from data in a larger list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591967/create-a-smaller-list-from-data-in-a-larger-list) when someone else was wanting the sort of the same thing. The only problem with the code at the end of the post is that if an answer in cells B1:B15 is changed and the original list gets smaller, numbers are duplicated at the end. For example, if questions 1,3,5,6 are incorrect and it populates that but I change an answer and then the incorrect questions are only 1,3,6 the list that is populated is 1,3,6,6. I don't know how to get rid of the duplicating numbers if the list updates and gets smaller. The code works fine if the list that is generated only gets bigger.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify your Excel version in tag, as your given example of solution is for pretty old version. With Excel 2019 and above you could use `FILTER`:

```
=FILTER(A2:C16,B2:B16=C2:C16)
```

Result:

[image]

Result is dynamic and it will change according to changes made to dataset.
You can put it anywhere you want. If you want it it another sheet, refer to data with sheet name, for example:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:C16,Sheet1!B2:B16<>Sheet1!C2:C16)
```